# How can I delete elements which do not contain matching inner element ClassName?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to delete list items which do not contain a specific set of class Names.

The HTML (simplified for this example) looks like this:

```
<ul class="myListItems">
  <li class="listTree">
    <a href=""> Link 1 </a>
  </li>
  <li class="listTree">
    <span class="treeIcon">&nbsp;</span>
    <a href=""> 
      <span class="draft"></span>
      <span class="redirect"></span>
      Link 2 
     </a>
  </li>
  
  <ul>
    <li class="listTree">
      <a href="">
        <span class="redirect"></span>
        Link 3
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do, is DELETE all elements **which do not** contain `<span class="redirect">` or `<span class="draft">`

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting. Then, if you do post, we expect that you'll show what you tried and report the exact results you got along with a specific question, rather than just "How do I do this?"

Comment: FYI, a list isn't a valid child of a list. You'll need to wrap it in a list _item_.  Since there's only one inner list item, though, I'm not sure why you'd need it  at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `li.querySelector()` to test whether the li contains an element matching a selector. You can use this to test if it contains either of the classes you want to keep.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => {
  if (!(li.querySelector(".draft") || li.querySelector(".redirect"))) {
    li.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="myListItems">
  <li class="listTree">
    <a href=""> Link 1 </a>
  </li>
  <li class="listTree">
    <span class="treeIcon">&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="">
      <span class="draft"></span>
      <span class="redirect"></span> Link 2
    </a>
  </li>

  <ul>
    <li class="listTree">
      <a href="">
        <span class="redirect"></span> Link 3
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've spent the past 3 hours trying overly complicated methods of achieving what you just did in just a few lines. Thank you for the support.